# Operating on function returns in Racket language

Tags: syntax, racket, return-value, call

So I have a function in Racket. This function which we will call my-function, returns a bag. Let us call this bag BagA. Let's assume this bag is (a). Now I want to work with this BagA. Let us say I want to take BagA and add it to another bag that we will call BagB. Let's say BagB is (b a a). When I add these two bags together I should get a new bag (a b a a). I believe all I need to do is to call my-function with some cons/append and I should be able to get the result I am looking for. The function my-function accepts two bags and returns one bag.

This is what I have tried for a call.

```
(my-function(cons BagB BagA) BagB)
```

I have also tried this.

```
(my-function (append BagB BagA) BagB)
```

Neither one of these return properly. They both return (b a a) instead of the expected (a b a a)

I also need to do something similar, but instead of adding BagA to BagB I would need to remove BagA from BagB. so, again, BagA is (a) this time  BagB is (a a b a), so, this time I would want the result to be(b a a).

I think my problem is with the syntax, but am not quite sure.

Any suggestions on how to properly call my-function to achieve the desired result?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but if you are trying to do something with the result then you are consing/appending in the wrong end. However:

Call my-function with BagB and BagA consed together as first argument and Bagb as second.

```
(my-function (cons BagB BagA) 
             BagB)
```

Call my-function with BagA and BagB as arguments and cons BagB in front of the result:

```
(cons BagB
      (my-function BagA BagB))
```

Sometimes it is clearer to name a result:

```
(let ((result-bag (my-function BagA BagB)))
  (cons BagB result-bag))
```

Also I don't understand the connection between the arguments being BagA and you calling the return BagA.

Comment: Thanks that worked for part of my problem. However for the other part I do feel I should use a name to work with, I have tried using (let ((new-bag (my-function BagA BagB)), however I am getting a syntax error: let: bad syntax  in: let, not sure how to solve that.

Comment: @terrylt1 `(let ((new-bag (my-function BagA BagB))` is one `)` short of being in the body part and then you'll need the final closing `)` after the code that uses that binding. Could it be that?